# How to create a SELECT element with an array of options using PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays

Simple question, with im sure a simple answer, I just cant get it working!!

I have a function which will be passed one of 5 `id`'s (for example "first", "second", ",third", "fourth" and "fifth").

Inside this function I want to refer to an array whose name is the `id` followed by `_array` (for example "first_array", "second_array" etc...)

How do I concatenate the id name passed to the function with the string "_array" ? I know how to do this in a string but not when referring to another variable!

To sum up i will have:

```
$i_d = "first"       //passed to my function
$string = "_array"
```

and I want to link to an array called:

```
$first_array
```

---

### ***EDIT***

My code is the following:

```
$option_timescale = array ( "1"=>"Immediately",
                            "2"=>"1 Month",
                            "3"=>"2 Months",
                            "4"=>"3 Months",
                            "5"=>"4 Months",
                            "6"=>"5 Months",
                            "7"=>"6 Months",
                            "8"=>"No Timescale"
                            );

$option_bus_route = array ( "1"=>"1 minute walk",
                            "2"=>"5 minute walk",
                            "3"=>"10 minute walk",
                            "4"=>"No Bus Needed"
                            );

$option_train_stat = array( "1"=>"5 minute walk",
                            "2"=>"10 minute walk",
                            "3"=>"5 minute drive",
                            "4"=>"10 minute drive",
                            "5"=>"No Train Needed"
                            );

function select_box($k,$v){ //$k is the id and $v is the description for the select boxes label


        $string = "option_";            //these two lines
        $option_array =$string . $k;    //are the troublemakers!

        $buffer = '<select name="' . $k . '" id="' . $k . '">';
        foreach ($option_array as $num=>$desc){
            $buffer .= '<option value="' . $num . '">' . $desc . '</option>';
        }//end foreach
        $buffer .= '</select>';
        $buffer .= '<label for="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</label>';

return $buffer;
}//end function
```

---

And the code which calls this function is:

```
function create_table($titles, $id) { //$titles is the relevant array from lists.php, $id is the id of the containing div

        $select = array('timescale','bus_route','train_stat');  //'select' id list
        $textarea = array('notes'); // 'textarea' id list   

        $buffer = '<div id="' . $id . '">';
        foreach ($titles as $k=>$v) { //$k is the database/id/name $v is the description text
            if (in_array($k,$select)){
                $buffer .= select_box($k,$v);
            }
            else if (in_array($k,$textarea)){
                $buffer .= text_box($k,$v);
            }
            else{
                $buffer .= check_box($k,$v);
            }
        }
        $buffer .= '</div>';
        echo $buffer;
    }
```

Comment: and many more: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+use+string+as+variable+name

Comment: While you can do this, it's usually the wrong approach. Use an associative array that uses `$i_d` as the index.

Comment: The original question was wrong; A typical [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Add $ to eval the string.

```
$i_d = "first";       
$string = "_array";
$myvar = $i_d . $string;
$$myvar = array('one','two','three');

print_r( $$myvar);
```